# Тип для хранения времени в С++

Tags: c++, время, c++17

У меня стоит задача написать функцию, которая получает от GPS и возвращает текущее время. В какой структуре или объекте, какого класса из стандартной библиотеки мне хранить это время? Мне нужно, что бы была возможность легко задавать и получать значения секунд, минут, часов и т.п. Т.е. что то типа

```
time_point time_now = now();
int hour = time_now.hour();
int second = time_now.second();
time_now.second = 0;
```

Сейчас у меня много где в коде используется std::chrono::time_point, но как, имея конкретный объект получить, например количество часов прошедших от начала суток я не знаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете воспользоваться [стандартной библиотекой C для работы с датой и временем](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/ctime):

```
std::time_t t = time(nullptr);
std::cout << localtime(&t)->tm_hour;
```

В C++20 в библиотеку `chrono` добавляются функции для работы с датой, временем, временными зонами, новые классы часов и т.д.
[подробнее на cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono)

Сейчас Вы можете, например, сконвертировать `time_point` в `std::time_t` и также использовать функции из стандартной библиотеки C:

```
using sc = std::chrono::system_clock;
std::time_t t = sc::to_time_t(sc::now());
std::cout << localtime(&t)->tm_hour;
```

В [`Boost` имеется библиотека `Date_Time`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/date_time.html)

В Qt также имеется класс для работы со временем - [QDateTime](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html).

Comment: Попробую завтра boost. У меня как раз притянут в этом проекте их циклический буфер и asio. По поводу 20го стандарта, даже если это появится сейчас в gcc(у меня gcc), это нормально использовать в своих проектах что-то из эксперементал? Чем это может грозить? Может получиться так что ваш код может перестать компилироваться в будущих версиях компилятора или начать вести себя немного по-другому из за изменений в библиотеке?

Answer (score 3):

Вам принципиальны "++"?
Если нет, то `gettimeofday()`, `localtime()`, `mktime()` и работы со `struct timeval` может быть достаточно.

Comment: На самом деле да. Я в своё время слишком сильно критиковал С, и убеждал всех своих коллег что в std всё намного лучше (кстати приводя им в пример хроно =)). Хоть это конечно может звучать глупо. Но всё равно большое спасибо за помощь.